# How do I find the number of times a character (entered by the user) is found within a string and return each of their index values?

Tags: vb.net

I've tried a few ways but none seem to get the result I want.

I'm using `Visual Basic 2010` Express.

What I currently have is:

```
Get selected word length

I=1
Count =1
FOR count to selectedword length
    IF Guess.Text = index of selected word THEN
        word index(I) =index
        Character = Guess.Text
        I = I + 1
    ENDIF
NEXT Count
```

Comment: You would use `String.IndexOf` in a loop.  Each time you find an index, you increment that to get the start index for the next call.

Answer (score 0):

I was just playing around with your problem here and this seems to work, I am fairly new to VB.NET so there is probably a much better way to do it but this seems to work:

```
    Dim FoundString As String, MyArray() As String, MyString As String, FindVal As String, MyVal As Long, X As Long
    MyString = "ABCDBEEBIIIIFBSB"
    FindVal = "B"
    MyArray = Split(MyString, FindVal)
    FoundString = ""
    For X = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray) - 1
        MyVal = MyVal + Len(MyArray(X)) + 1
        FoundString = FoundString & CStr(MyVal) & ","
    Next
    FoundString = Left(FoundString, Len(FoundString) - 1)
    MsgBox(FoundString)
```

FoundString contains the locations of the string you are searching for (in my case "B") in Comma seperated format. If you need it as an array you can use split to push it to an array.

My logic was: Take the string and split it into an array on the letter we are looking to match.

Build a string of values adding the length of each element of the array along with a comma.

This should be quicker than looping each char of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely for me:

```
    Dim text = "ABCDBEEBIIIIFBSB"
    Dim guess = "B"
    Dim indices = _
        text _
            .Select(Function(x, n) New With _
                { _
                    .index = n, _
                    .found = text.Substring(n).StartsWith(guess) _
                }) _
            .Where(Function(x) x.found) _
            .Select(Function(x) x.index) _
            .ToArray()
```

It returns `{ 1, 4, 7, 13, 15 }`. Since `indices` is an array it is very easy to determine the `.Length` of the array to know how many matches were found.

The use of `text.Substring(n).StartsWith(guess)` allows the `guess` to be multiple characters. The query could be simplified if `guess` could be made to be a character.

Here is the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8z47bW) to play with the code.